# CREATE TYPE and casting problems on numerics in Postgres 11.7

Tags: postgresql, casting

I ran into a problem the other day I'm hoping to sort out. I'm generating a lot of scores/measures in the 0-1 range. By default, you get a whole lot of digits:

```
select (3/5.3);               -- 0.56603773584905660377
```

Our source data isn't accurate enough for 20 decimals, and I'd like to use 6:

```
select (3/5.3)::decimal(8,6); -- 0.566038
```

I'd like to have a custom type named `decimal_score` for convenience, and in case I figure out we should use a different umber of digits. (For now, we're testing things out, so reworking the data if we change the decimals isn't a problem, at the moment.)

```
CREATE TYPE decimal_score AS (
   score decimal(8,6));
```

It *seems* like the following should now work, but it does not:

```
select (3/5.3)::decimal_score; -- ERROR:  cannot cast type numeric to decimal_score.
```

I've looked at the manuals:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createcast.html

And this detailed post:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203934/postgresql-alternative-to-sql-server-s-try-cast-function

It sounds like an explicit `from:to` function is required in Postgres for *any* type conversion. I was hoping (assuming) that implicit conversions exist for numerics. In fact, the original statement does work:

```
select (3/5.3)::decimal(8,6); -- 0.566038
```

How can I get that same result for my custom type? And, do I need to `CREATE CAST` for *every* possible numeric source type? I'm hoping for something implicit, or a shortcut.

Below are some experiments, none of which are quite right. The closest gets me back a record-format value instead of the bare number:

```
select (3/5.3)::decimal_score; -- (0.566038)  <-- Parens, like a Postgres (record) wrapper.
```

Here are the experiments:

```
-- WITHOUT FUNCTION
DROP CAST IF EXISTS (numeric AS decimal_score);
CREATE CAST (numeric AS decimal_score)
     WITHOUT FUNCTION
     AS ASSIGNMENT;              -- ERROR:  source and target data types are not physically compatible. (Line 12)


DROP CAST IF EXISTS (numeric AS decimal_score);
CREATE CAST (numeric AS decimal_score)
     WITHOUT FUNCTION
     AS IMPLICIT;              -- ERROR:  source and target data types are not physically compatible. (Line 12)


-- WITH INOUT
DROP CAST IF EXISTS (numeric AS decimal_score);
CREATE CAST (numeric AS decimal_score)
    WITH INOUT
    AS ASSIGNMENT;

select (3/5.3)::decimal_score; -- ERROR:  malformed record literal: "0.56603773584905660377"

DROP CAST IF EXISTS (numeric AS decimal_score);
CREATE CAST (numeric AS decimal_score)
    WITH INOUT
    AS IMPLICIT;

select (3/5.3)::decimal_score; -- ERROR:  malformed record literal: "0.56603773584905660377"


-- WITH FUNCTION
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION types.cast_numeric_as_decimal_score(numeric) RETURNS decimal_score
    AS 'select $1::decimal(8,6);'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

DROP CAST IF EXISTS (numeric AS decimal_score);
CREATE CAST (numeric AS decimal_score)
    WITH FUNCTION cast_numeric_as_decimal_score(numeric)
    AS ASSIGNMENT;

select (3/5.3)::decimal_score; -- (0.566038)


DROP CAST IF EXISTS (numeric AS decimal_score);
CREATE CAST (numeric AS decimal_score)
    WITH FUNCTION cast_numeric_as_decimal_score(numeric)
    AS IMPLICIT;

select (3/5.3)::decimal_score; -- (0.566038)
```

## Answer

I tried out Belayer's answer, and it works perfectly. I do not know why this works, but it does:

```
DROP DOMAIN IF EXISTS domains.decimal_score;

CREATE DOMAIN domains.decimal_score AS
    DECIMAL(8,6)
    NOT NULL;

SELECT (3/5.3)::decimal_score;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a domain having the definition you want. This is then used the same a a native definition (at least in most cases);

```
create domain decimal_score decimal(8,6);
create table cont_decimal(num decimal_score);
insert into  cont_decimal(num) values (3/5.3);
select * from cont_decimal;
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. Any idea why a domain behaves differently than a type? I thought that domains were extended types plus rules. The automatic casting seems like a good deal more than that.

Comment: I do not specifically know. But if I have to venture a guess then a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/domains.html) has been described as an alias for a single data type. A [type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) is a much more complex object.  I guess  for consistency a domain could have been defined as the 6th form of create type. But then I have never seen or even heard of any large software application being completely consistent.

Comment: That's some helpful speculation. I'll file it under "that's how things are". I'm quite happy that domains work well here. I already like them for a range of other purposes, so no complaints.